# R graphic points segments

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graphics

I have to make a graphic in R in order to draw the points and the segments on it.
I need to do exactly the same thing for W2, W3, W4 on the same graphic, but I do not know how to add it on the first graphic.For W2 x should be 2, for w3 should be 3 and so on.Also, could someone tell me how could it be possible to do this with a for and also apper in the same graphic?
I want also to somehow draw the lines beween a point and its coordinates on the axis with a dashed line.

```
 w1<-c(-0.931,-3.858,3.1946,1.2263)
    w2<-c(-0.1075,-1.4753,-2.4762,1.9593)
    w3<-c(-0.6301,0.7811,1.5725,0.1442)
    w4<-c(0.6267,-1.2948,-0.1932,-0.5225)
    w5<-c(0.1683,-0.2534,0.0937,-0.2469)
    cent<-cbind(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5)
    cent
    comp<-c("W1","W2","W3","W4","W5")
    plot(c(1,1,1,1),y=cent[,1], xlab="Componente",ylab="Centroid",pch=19)
    segments(1,max(cent[,1]),1,min(cent[,1]) )

    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(centroizi_w, aes(x=c(1,1,1,1), y=cent[,1]))   +
      geom_point()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tidyr` to convert your df to long format, then group by key (i.e. the W value)...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
centroizi_w <- gather(as.data.frame(centroizi)) #this converts the matrix to a df, 
                         #then to long format, with default columns 'value' and 'key'

ggplot(centroizi_w, aes(x=as.numeric(as.factor(key)), y=value, group=key))   +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

If you have more than ten values of W, then you would be better using `x=as.numeric(gsub("W","",key))` in the above, as the factor approach will sort alphabetically rather than numerically!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to start with. I had a hard time figuring out what the segments and the dashed lines were for, so might need some more work.

```
library(dplyr)
centroizi <- as.data.frame(centroizi)

centroizi <- centroizi %>%
  gather(Key, Value) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(substr(Key, 2, 2)))

ggplot(centroizi) + 
 geom_point(aes(x=x, y=Value, colour = Key)) +
 geom_line(aes(x=x, y=Value, colour = Key))
```